# Issue with contextual help overwriting existing content

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, contextual-help, screen-options

I'm missing something here:

```
function page_help($contextual_help, $screen_id, $screen) {

if ($screen_id == 'page') {

    $contextual_help = '
    <h5>Shortcodes</h5>
    <p>Shortcodes help</p>
    '.$contextual_help;

    return $contextual_help;
}

elseif ($screen_id == 'post') {

    $contextual_help = '
    <h5>Post help</h5>
    <p>Help is on its way!</p>
    '.$contextual_help;

    return $contextual_help;
}
}       

add_filter('contextual_help', 'page_help', 10, 3);
```

The code is inserting into the correct screens but I am having two issues:

1. The code is inserting at the top, I'd like it at the bottom.
2. The code is deleting the help from all other screens except those mentioned above.

Thanks in advance for your tips!

Niels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not delete help from all other screens, you need to always return the contextual help text, otherwise your filter doesn't return anything for non-page/post screens and so nothing will show up. Move the return to the bottom of the function, outside of your if/else. Also, the original contextual help is being concatenated to the end of your custom message, so move it to the front to have your text put at the bottom. Thus:

```
function myprefix_page_help($contextual_help, $screen_id, $screen) {

  if ($screen_id == 'page') {
    $contextual_help = $contextual_help.'
    <h5>Shortcodes</h5>
    <p>Shortcodes help</p>';
  }

  elseif ($screen_id == 'post') {
    $contextual_help = $contextual_help.'
    <h5>Post help</h5>
    <p>Help is on its way!</p>';
  }

  return $contextual_help;
}       

add_filter('contextual_help', 'myprefix_page_help', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Hey thanks @helenyhou!!!! And you even helped me understand more about WP!

Comment: Oops! Spoke too soon. Its failing for some reason...

Comment: @Niels Oeltjen What exactly is failing? Are you getting an error message? I didn't test the code, so it's possible that I have a typo in there. Also, you should always prefix your functions to prevent collisions and I forgot to do so above, so I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry @helenyhou, it was a simple issue in the end: clashing plugin that I neglected to turn off. I discovered the clash by applying namespacing to find that page_help was running in that plugin (by sheer coincidence). Funnily enough though, no error reporting...